# SQL Server CE distribution

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sqlite, sql-server-ce

I have spent several days trying to solve this problem with no luck and my requirements are really simple - I want to make an application with **database** which will work on most PCs (without DB server installed) and I want to use **LINQ**. For the compatibility reasons I want to use **.NET framework 3.5** (every Windows 7 machine has it).

I have tried 2 ways: SQL Server CE and SQLite.

### SQL Server CE

Although Visual Studio does not support LINQ for Compact Version of SQL server, I have found simple workaround - generating .dbml file using metal.exe tool from Visual Studio and then dragging it into project. My application works fine on my machine, but when I copy it somewhere else, it crashes. I have copied all dlls from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\3.5 and tried 4.0 too. I think problem is that my app is not looking for dlls (references) inside its directory. I managed to get it work using DataSets (without LINQ), where I manually add reference to SQLServerCE and check CopyLocal to true. BUT when I use LINQ, there is no reference to SQLServerCE in project references and it is working. I don't know how to change it. Or is there a problem somewhere else?

### SQLite

After long messing with SQL Server CE, I have tried SQLite. I am very disappointed how poor is SQLite support in .NET. I had to download older version of ADO.NET provider (newer versions does not add SQLite Database into my Visual Studio 2010 - I don't understand why but I googled that it is normal and I have to install old version and then replace it with newer). Then I downloaded dblinq (I have discovered that this project is dead later) and after some messing with dbmetal and dlls I get rid of errors in Visual Studio and compiled my application. But I can't run it, it always crashes on error 40 - like there was no SQLite server. Of course I have copied all dlls. I can't run it even on my development machine.

I am very surprised that it is nearly impossible to create simple database application in C# .NET which will not bother client with servers etc.

Please is there anyone who made SQL CE work with LINQ and mainly who made his app distributable?

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us the error message that's in the event log after the application crashes with SQL CE...

Comment: It crashes on context creation - db = new MyDatabase(@"MyDatabase.sdf");

Message: Cannot open MyDatabase.sdf. Provider System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5 not installed.

Comment: I made it work, there was 3.5.1 version for some reason in references I had to add application configuration file and specify it there. THANKS!

Comment: See my blogpost here for details: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try using the nuget Entity Framework for SQL CE package. It will download all the required assemblies to make it work.
http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/